# UITabBarController with unselected tab

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view controller say 'HomeViewController' on which I have added a `UITabBarController`, which has 4 `UITabBarItems`. Now what I want is, when I select the HomeViewController no tab should should be selected for the first time and another view should be loaded. I have tried UITabBar instead of UITabBarController but its not working.  I have also tried :

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController=nil; //giving crash
tabBarController.selectedIndex=-1;   //not working either
```

`UITabBarItems` should be selected when user will click on them.

Comment: What does the crash say? According to the docs, nil should be a legal value for the selectedRootViewController, but maybe some other control is expecting it to be non-nil.

Comment: Crash :- [UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected.'

Comment: Here is the link of what I wanted... http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/ios-dev-add-tabbar-to-a-view-without-a-tabbarcontroller/

Answer (score 1):

You have to add UITabBar object on HomeViewController.

In ViewDidLoad you have to add following code:

```
ViewController1 *controller1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];
ViewController2 *controller2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
viewControllersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:controller1,controller2, nil];

tabBarController =  [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:viewControllersArray];
for(int i = 0; i < tabBarController.tabBar.items.count; i++){
    [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:i] setTitle:[[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:i] title]];
}

isItemSelected = NO;
```

Also set the tag of tab bar items starting from 0. As 0 for first item, 1 for second item and so on.

and implement delegate method:

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar1 didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

  ```
  if(!isItemSelected){
      isItemSelected = YES;
      AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
      appDel.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
  }


  tabBarController.selectedIndex = item.tag;
  tabBarController.selectedViewController = [viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:item.tag];
  ```

}

Comment: How should I open the view Controllers on selecting the tabs.. I knw I can do it using didSelectItem delegate.. But don't know how to do that. like if we use UITabBarController, tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects: settingsNav, searchNav,favorNav,newsfeedNav,messagingNav, nil]; is used to set view controllers

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the right way, as Concept of creating TabBar says that " Show the particular controller of related tab". If u do not select any tab than what else you will show on screen, "A black screen ?". so please re-architecture your design.

Comment: No, not a black screen but . view or view controller

Comment: when no tab is selected, which view controller you wanna to show on screen ?

Comment: Whatever View controller it is.. I think view controller name is not important. ok.. Lets say I wanna show a blank screen.. How will iI Do that..